# Magento removes script tag

Tags: magento, markup

i have some trouble with Magento (Magento Version 1.5.1.0).
Does Magento do some output / markup / js filtering?

I have put some script tags inside a *.phtml Template (no CMS Block)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// echo foo
function foo() {
}
</script>
```

When i look at the html-source, this tag is missing. All other surrounding tags are visible.
I checked the template path and cleared the cache. Any hints or ideas?

Kind Regards

Comment: Are you sure you are editing the right template file? try outputting something unique in the phtml to test.

Comment: hi, i have put some debug divs before and after - these tags are visible. This was my test to ensure it is the right template - Like:
<div id="debug-1">debug-1</div><script>...</script><div id="debug-2">debug-2</div>

The output is:

<div id="debug-1">debug-1</div><div id="debug-2">debug-2</div>

Comment: maybe put the inner content in: <![CDATA[

Comment: hi - thx - tried it - does not change the behaviour. Never had such a problem. Spooky :-) I have deleted the cache and it the right template file.

Comment: yea that's definitely weird, try addding it to a dedicated js file.

Comment: Where did you put that code? Is it an AJAX? Which controller and block?

Comment: I'm talking about template/checkout/onepage/review/info.phtml

Comment: I have moved the JS code to an external file - but inline-JS would be the better solution.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, very weird. Any solutions? I need to add some dynamic variables ...

Comment: Coming across this a couple years later. I put some markup around a script tag and it displays but the script does not. This is markup generated via AJAX. I suspect the third-party module is loading the block via AJAX by creating/modifying the layout and rendering the layout instead of simply using `$this->getResponse()->setBody($block->toHtml());`

Comment: ... and to add that I ended up finding the cause inside a custom `_eval()` javascript method that strips `<script>` from content loaded via AJAX. The vendor is MageWorx, so if you want to avoid this kind of problem, avoid their products.

Comment: Might be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36922262/inline-javascript-is-getting-stripped-off-from-the-ajax-response-by-prototype-js

Answer (score 2):

I had the same weird issue, with making it clear that no caches were involved and it's not caused by browser plugins. For what it's worth: The javascript get's executed but variables have to be declared like this:

```
// Not working
var foo = 'baz';
// Working
window.foo = 'baz';
```

Don't ask me why.

Answer (score 1):

No, out of the box Magento's Layout/Block/`phtml` system doesn't do any HTML filtering and/ro escaping.

My initial guess would be you're editing the wrong `phtml` template file — maybe you're in the wrong theme?

A secondary guess would be you're dealing with a block/template that's cached, so your changes won't show up until the cache is expired or you manually clear it.

More context in your question would help people come up with a solution.

Comment: Hi - it ist the the right template - because my debug markup before and after the script tag is visible. i cleared the cache after each change

Answer (score 0):

Same issue today here, it was HF_Defer extension causing that. When you have this problem it will be faster way to create folder temremove inside app/etc/modules. Then just move all files from custom module to that folder. Then put it back 5 by 5 of them to see when it start/stops working properly.