# Inline javascript is getting stripped off from the AJAX response by Prototype JS Ajax.Request method

Tags: ajax, magento, magento-1.7, prototypejs

I am working on a Magento store trying to code a widget's javascript layer with the help of Prototype js framework.

In my grid.js file AJAX call is setup like that:

```
loadTabContent: function(tab, tabType){

        if(tab === undefined || tabType === undefined){
            return this;
        }

        entityId = tab.id.split('-')[3];

        request = new Ajax.Request(
            this.tabContentLoadUrl,
            {
                method:'get', 
                onSuccess: this.onTabContentLoad.bind(tab),
                onFailure: this.ajaxFailure.bind(this),
                evalJS: true,
                parameters: {
                    id: entityId, 
                    type: tabType
                }
            }
        );
    }
```

Below is the success handler:

```
onTabContentLoad: function(transport){

        if(transport && typeof transport.responseText !== undefined){
            try{
                response = transport.responseText;
            }catch (e) {
                console.log('PARSE ERROR', e);
                response = {};
            }

            entityId = this.id.split('-')[3];
            tabType = this.id.split('-')[1];

            if(response && $('tab-' + tabType + '-' + entityId + '-contents')){
                $('tab-' + tabType + '-' + entityId + '-contents').update(response);    
            }
        }
    },
```

The content for the div is getting updated correctly by the AJAX call but there is some inline JS in response which is not working. 
**I can't even see that javascript snippet in Elements tab(chrome developer tool)**

Below is the code that handles the AJAX request on server side:

```
public function renderTabContentAction()
    {
        $entityId = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        if( ! $entityId){

            $this->getResponse()->setHeader('HTTP/1.0', '400', true);
            $this->getResponse()->setBody('Invalid parameters provided.');
        }

        $tabType = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('type');
        if( ! $tabType){

            $this->getResponse()->setHeader('HTTP/1.0', '400', true);
            $this->getResponse()->setBody('Invalid parameters provided.');
        }

        Mage::register('current_entity_id', $entityId);
        Mage::register('current_tab_type', $tabType);

        $tabHtml = $this->_getTabsHtml($entityId, $tabType);    


        $this->getResponse()->setHeader('HTTP/1.0', '200', true);
        $this->getResponse()->setBody($tabHtml);
    }
```

Below is the response that gets passed to onTabContentLoad AJAX handler:

```
 <div class="vertical-tabs">
      <div class="tabs">
        <div class="tab" id="tab-vertical-137-2441">
          <input type="radio" id="label-vertical-product-tab-137-2441" name="product-tab-group-137">
          <label class="tabs-label" for="label-vertical-product-tab-137-2441">PG-10ml</label>
          <div class="content" id="tab-vertical-137-2441-contents">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab" id="tab-vertical-137-2442">
          <input type="radio" id="label-vertical-product-tab-137-2442" name="product-tab-group-137">
          <label class="tabs-label" for="label-vertical-product-tab-137-2442">PG-15ml</label>
          <div class="content" id="tab-vertical-137-2442-contents">
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
     bulkOrderGrid.initVerticalTabs();
     bulkOrderGrid.activateTab('2441', 'VERTICAL');
   </script>
```

You can see that the SCRIPT tags are there in the response. Its just when the content gets updated using **Element.update** function it strips off the SCRIPT tags. That's what I can understand so far.

**NOTE:**
I have also used **Ajax.Updater** along with **evalScripts:true** and **Ajax.Request** along with **evalJS:true**.

Got stuck here. Any help would be much appreciated.

**UPDATES:**

Since I am using **Element.update** function to refresh the section. The source of the problem is this part of the code in **prototype.js** around line no. 2048. I can see its getting executed in js debugger. It does evaluates the js code but also removes the SCRIPT tags from the source. Commenting out **stripScripts** works fine.

```
   else {
     element.innerHTML = content.stripScripts();
   }

   content.evalScripts.bind(content).defer();
```

Comment: You are correct  **Element.update** remove script tag. you should use  **Element.innerHTML**

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that
the Ajax response is passed through `String#evalScripts()` but the context is not the global context so instead of your script block do this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 window.bulkOrderGrid.initVerticalTabs();
 window.bulkOrderGrid.activateTab('2441', 'VERTICAL');
</script>
```

if that doesnt fix it - than you can directly run `transport.responseText.evalScripts()` but you still need the `window.` in your script block to resolve the scope of the variables.

Comment: I've tried your suggestions too. But no success. Going to update this question with some new findings. Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 0):

> You are correct Element.update() remove script tag. you should use
>   Element.innerHTML